Multivariable Linear Regression with Gradient Descent Error
I am following a tutorial from this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCOHri09YmM), but I am getting an error "invalid value encountered in subtract coeff = coeff - der", and then my Final values of coefficients are [nan nan nan].  Below is my code
#Gradient Descent Algorithm
learning_rate = 0.01 #step size
epochs = 2000
N = y.size
np.random.seed(123)
coeff = np.random.rand(3)
print("Initial values of coefficients : ", coeff)

#Algorithm
def gD(x, y, coeff, epochs, learning_rate):
    past_costs = []
    past_coeff = [coeff]
    for i in range(epochs):
        prediction = np.dot(x, coeff)
        error = prediction - y
        cost = 1/(2*N) * np.dot(error.T,error)
        past_costs.append(cost)
        der = (1/N) * learning_rate * np.dot(x.T, error)
        coeff = coeff - der
        past_coeff.append(coeff)
    return past_coeff, past_costs

past_coeff, past_costs = gD(x, y, coeff, epochs, learning_rate)
coeff = past_coeff[-1]

print("Find values of coefficients : ",coeff)


I am trying to expect to see the final values of coefficients.

Can you add your full code, inputs and expected outputs?

your code is correct. Just increase the number of epochs eg to 20000 and try with a simple dataset eg iris. or a simple randomly generated dataset

I checked the code in the link you shared. There is a paranthesis mistake in the code.
Instead of using:
x1 = (x1 - x1.mean() / x1.std())
x2 = (x2 - x2.mean() / x2.std())

you should use:
x1 = (x1 - x1.mean()) / x1.std()
x2 = (x2 - x2.mean()) / x2.std()

